# How to upload pic in website using vbs script?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, qtp

I am trying to upload a file in website using VBS. but when upload button is clicked a pop up window is open, requesting to "Choose File to Upload".

Here I am unable to set path and click "Open" button.

[image: script to perform action]

Below is my script:

```
Dim URL 
Dim IE 

Set IE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
URL = "set url here" 


IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate URL

 Do While IE.Busy
    WScript.Sleep 100
 Loop

 IE.Document.getElementById("uploadLink").Click
 IE.Document.getElementById("attachCV").Click
```

Please help me for next steps:

- a.How to Set path in popup window?
- b. How to click Open button to select the
     file?

Comment: If it is an option, for tasks like this I recommend [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/).

Comment: Thanks sylverac... but i am bounded to use VBS only.

Comment: Is there a Text box before the Upload button in your site? If so directly send the keys(The file path) to your Textbox

Comment: @Sive - click on "Browse" button a pop up window opens there i have to set file location. and then open button must be click. Similar to uploading your profile pic in facebook where it asks for pic to select from your folder.

Comment: You cannot set the filename via code, as if you could set it via code it would allow any code to upload a file to a webpage without a person needing to click anything.  That would be a major security vulnerability.  So browsers prevent this from happening

Comment: @Dijkgraaf can't be done with cURL..

Comment: @ern In his comments he says he can only use VBS (VBScript).  So cURL would not be an option.  It looks like he is trying to automate a test, but browser security is stopping that automation.

Comment: Guys, I tried with selenium and i worked fine. Thanks a lot for responding.

Answer (score 0):

When you see this pop up, the default focus would be set to the file name already. You just need to use VBS (SendKeys) method to send the file path and Hit enter (again using SendKeys method) to close the popup.

http://ss64.com/vb/sendkeys.html

Comment: You might be correct. need to try this. however I am able to automate this using selenium. Thanks a lot for responding!